# (Javascript) How do I add a countdown timer to a selection option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to add a countdown timer to a selection option. This is a snippet of the html code:

```
<select id="patientSelect">
<option> Heart Attack, 65, ETA: <span id="timer"></span></option>
</select>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=30;
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer(){
    count--;
    if(count <= 0){
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs";
}
});
```

But it only shows up if I put the id in the option tag (which also removes all the current html). Any help is appreciated. :-)

Edit: Perfect, thanks guys!

Comment: That's because your markup is invalid, `option` elements can't have children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<select id="patientSelect">
<option id="timer">Heart Attack, 65, ETA: 30 secs</option>
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=30;
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer(){
    count--;
    if(count <= 0){
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML= "Heart Attack, 65, ETA: " + (count.toString()) + " secs";
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your markup is invalid, `option` elements can't have children, you can select the `option`and prepend the original string using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = 'Heart Attack, 65, ETA:' +  count + " secs";
```